# Configuring Weblogic 12c with Arquillian(Remote Container) - java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, maven, weblogic12c, jboss-arquillian

I'm stuck trying configure Arquillian(Remote Container) with Weblogic 12c. I tried few times following a bunch of tutorial around the web, including official arquillian website. As I said, was frustating.
I made all the changes : Added all dependencies(pom.xml), added a profile pom.xml - and activated it - and created a test class with arquillian's annotations. Before run the test I started weblogic and I got this stack below.
I'm running out of possibility.

Stack :

```
    Caused by: javax.management.ReflectionException: null
at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:237)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:300)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_1211_WLStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.management.remote.common.RMIConnectionWrapper$16.run(ClientProviderBase.java:918)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
at weblogic.security.Security.runAs(Security.java:61)
at weblogic.management.remote.common.RMIConnectionWrapper.invoke(ClientProviderBase.java:916)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:1022)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicJMXClient.doDeploy(WebLogicJMXClient.java:211)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicJMXClient.deploy(WebLogicJMXClient.java:97)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.jmx.FullJMXRemoteContainer.deploy(FullJMXRemoteContainer.java:64)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.remote_12_1_2.WebLogicContainer.deploy(WebLogicContainer.java:61)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: deploy(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,) for com.bea:Name=DeploymentManager,Type=DeploymentManager
at weblogic.management.jmx.modelmbean.WLSModelMBean.invoke(WLSModelMBean.java:395)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:762)
at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.internal.FederatedMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(FederatedMBeanServerInterceptor.java:349)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$16.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:449)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:447)
at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.invoke(JMXContextInterceptor.java:263)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$16.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:449)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:447)
at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityMBeanMgmtOpsInterceptor.invoke(SecurityMBeanMgmtOpsInterceptor.java:65)
```

Arquilian.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
            http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<container qualifier="wls-integration" default="true">
    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />    
    <configuration>
        <property name="adminUrl">t3://localhost:7001</property>
        <property name="adminUserName">weblogic</property>
        <property name="adminPassword">welcome1</property>
        <property name="target">AdminServer</property>
        <property name="wlHome">C://as//Oracle//Middleware//wlserver_12.1</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

Pom-Dependencies :

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- ###################################### -->
    <!-- #### Arquillian Test  Dependencies ### -->
    <!-- ###################################### -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- ###################################### -->
    <!-- ####      Tests Dependencies       ### -->
    <!-- ###################################### -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1.2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>             
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>     
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Class :

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestWls {

@Deployment(testable = false)
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class,"test.war")
        .addPackage(Test.class.getPackage()).addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}

@Test
public void test() {    
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

}

Profile with wls-maven-plugin :

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>wls-integration</id>

     <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>

     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1.2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>             
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     <build>
            <plugins>
                  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                  </plugin>
                  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>

                   <plugin>
                          <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
                          <artifactId>wls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>12.1.1.0</version>
                     <configuration>
                         <adminmode>true</adminmode>
                         <adminurl>${weblogic.adminurl}</adminurl>
                         <user>${weblogic.username}</user>
                         <password>${weblogic.user.pwd}</password>
                         <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
                         <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
                         <middlewareHome>${middleware.home}</middlewareHome>
                         <weblogicHome>${weblogic.home}</weblogicHome>
                         <domainHome>${weblogic.domain}</domainHome>
                     </configuration>
                      <executions> 
                         <execution>
                            <id>up</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase> 
                            <goals> 
                              <goal>deploy</goal> 
                            </goals>
                          </execution> 
                          <execution>
                            <id>down</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase> 
                            <goals> 
                              <goal>undeploy</goal> 
                            </goals>
                          </execution> 
                       </executions> 
                   </plugin>
            </plugins>
     </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Could be as simple as a version difference.  Can you open that JAR, find that class, and look at the method signatures?  One might have changed.

Comment: The method doesn't exist indeed. The class weblogic.management.jmx.modelmbean.WLSModelMBean is from wlfullclient.jar . This package I got from weblogic directory - {WLHOME.}/server/lib. Should I change this particular package?

Comment: Find a version that has the method you need and update your dependencies.  Repeat until all the issues are resolved.